# Exporting for All iPhones in Sketch 3

Tags: ios, iphone, sketch-3, sketchapp

There seems to be a confusion for me regarding Sketch 3 workflow and exporting Artboards for all iPhones in Sketch 3.

- I understand that 1x resolution is for iPhone 3GS and below, 2x for
  iPhone 4/4S/5/5S/6/6S and 3x is for 6Plus. So does that mean If I
  create Artboards for iPhone 6 and export in 2x it would be for iPhone
  4/5/6 and if I export at 3x it would be for 6plus regardless of what 
  dartboard I'm using?
- Or should I have different dartboards for each iPhone and export @1x @2x and @3x for each of them?

I have been looking for a solid answer for days but could not find one that actually works. According to this [link](http://sketchtalk.io/discussion/1225/designing-and-exporting-for-all-iphones-confusion) :

> "if you were designing at 1x with the 6Plus (414x736) art board, exporting your assets at 1x would be for 3G/3GS devices, 2x would be for 4/4S/5/5S/6 devices, and finally 3x would be for the 6Plus."

However after I tested that I get different results:
Exporting iPhone 6Plus (414x736) at 1x = 414x736 2x = 828x1472 and 3x = 1242x2208. Shouldn't that be 750x1334 for 2x ?

- What if I want to use PDF vector assets so I don't have to export 1x, 2x and 3x separately. Which Artboard should I export the 1x PDF from?
- Overall I'd love to know what's the best approach to design and export for multiple iPhones.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

The density selection in Zeplin is a way of telling the app that, the Sketch artboards are in @1x or @2x or @3x. So, Zeplin will calculate the assets size based on that. You don't have to work on different sizes (@1x, @2x, @3x & PDF).

If your Sketch artboard is 1242 x 2208 pixels (iPhone 6Plus, 6S Plus, 7Plus) then you have to choose the density as @3x in Zeplin.

So make sure you select the right density in Zeplin.

[Zeplin – Choosing right screen size while importing from Sketch?](http://blog.mallow-tech.com/2016/01/zeplin-choosing-right-screen-size-while-importing-from-sketch/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the smaller to bigger approach. If your design work on the smaller screen it should be fine on other.

So I start with a 375x667px artboard and then export the assets as @1 @2 for iPhone and @3 to sizes plus.

[image: Example of Asset]